# Not able to call Vue component in vue cli application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I am trying to create the component for tile which can be used in multiple views. I have called the component in view but it is not working

Code of component (Tile.vue)

```
 <template>
        <div class="tile">
            <label class="title">Tile Title</label>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'CustomTile'
    }
    </script>

    <style scoped lang="less">
    .tile { width:248px;
    height: 126px;
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
        .title {
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
    }
    </style>
```

code of view (Report.vue) where I am trying to call above component

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class="topnav">
  <button type="button">Expand/Collapse</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <CustomTile></CustomTile>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomTile from '@/components/Tile.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Report'
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}
</style>
```

CustomTile is not getting rendered. I am not able to figure out what/where is the problem.

Comment: Do you have some error in the console?

Comment: No, 
I forgot to add "components: {
    CustomTile
  }"....after adding that, its working now..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly import the component in the parent where you want to use it and register it:

`Report.vue:`

```
<script>
import CustomTile from '@/components/Tile.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Report',
  components: {
    CustomTile
  }
}
</script>
```

And then, since `CustomTile` is a CamelCase component name, you need to use the following notation:

`<custom-tile></custom-tile>`